# Merging 2 branches without making working copy

Tags: svn

In one SVN repo there is 2 branch (trunk and TEST).

How to merge all changes from trunk to TEST branch directly without doing the checkout of these 2 branches.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read `svn help merge` again: you have to have **one** branch in WC (target of merge), WCless merge in SVN is impossible